# unable to configure vite.js for my react app

Tags: npm, vite, react-typescript

after creating vite, i did npm install but just before successful installation, it terminates with this error npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ademidun\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-20T07_59_04_841Z-debug-0.log

Ademidun@hassan MINGW32 ~/Desktop/My-Portfolio/my-react-app (main)
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ademidun\Desktop\My-Portfolio\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:865
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Ademidun\Desktop\My-Portfolio\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild --version
npm ERR! node:child_process:924
npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Users\Ademidun\Desktop\My-Portfolio\my-react-app\node_modules@esbuild\win32-ia32\esbuild.exe UNKNOWN
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1110:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:871:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:914:15)
npm ERR!     at Object. (C:\Users\Ademidun\Desktop\My-Portfolio\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:220:28)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   errno: -4094,
npm ERR!   code: 'UNKNOWN',

i tried re-installing, but there are no changes and npm run dev throws module not found error for vite.js

Comment: apparently it was a network problem. i solved my connectivity issues and it was resolved.